# MS Access - Disable Update on a Certain Field or Column

Tags: vba, ms-access

How do we disable update or edit on a certain column for a record. For example I have Product table with fields of ID, Description, Count. I want to disable the changes on Description only. I know how to do this in sql, but how about in a program for Access or VBA code?

Comment: This is as close as you can get http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3905921/Leveraging-Data-Macro-in-Microsoft-Access-2010.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a form to present the data using  a text box control bound to the field, you can lock the field for edits in the field properties.  The property is called "locked".

You can also use vba code to lock and unlock the field under certain conditions.

```
Sub form_current ()
If x = "superuser" then
Me!SalaryField.enabled=true
Me!SalaryField.locked=false
Else
Me!Salaryfield.enabled=false 
Me!Salaryfield.locked=true
End if
End Sub
```